# Get path independ from os and create file two defined dirs up?

Tags: python

i try to run a pythonscript (test.py) manually from a folder and it needs to determine the path depending on os and have to create a file two folders up.

Like this:

```
projectfolder
|-created_file
|
-folder1
 |
 |
 -folder2
  |-test.py
```

How do i get the path depending on the os? And how do i remove the path parts folder2, folder1 and / or \ (depending on os) to get the root of the project?

This file should be able to run via click. I already tried some solutions without success.

Do you guys have a clue?

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', '..', 'test.txt'), 'w')
```

***The TREE Path***

```
\---projectfolder
|   test.txt
|
\---folder1
    \---folder2
            test.py
```

***Details***

You first get the current directory of your script by using

> os.path.dirname( __ file __ )

Normally we use "**..**" to go up one directory

So you join the directory path with 2 folders up using ..

> os.path.join()

You can read the full docs here [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)

Comment: I had excat this solution but without os.path.join(). Oh man thx. Would give upvote but i cant.